# Virtualbox Guest Additions Requires Virtualbox on Guest Machine?

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I'm trying to install Virtualbox Guest Additions on a Debian system, but the manual says I need vboxdrv on the guest machine. Does this mean I need to install Virtualbox on the guest machine as well?

I tried running VBoxLinuxAdditions.run before installing virtualbox and it gave me this:

> You appear to have a version of the VBoxGuestAdditions software on
>   your system which was installed from a different source or using a
>   different type of installer.

Is is because the system doesn't have virtualbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux distro's come with the Open-Source version of the VirtualBox guest additions installed. When you run the script on the virtual CD, it is warning you that it is about to overwrite the one installed by (in your case) Debian. Go ahead and proceed with the overwriting, and then reboot the virtual machine. You'll know it's working when you get the full size screen.

You are NOT required to install VB on the guest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you clearing that up. While I think it works in general, I'm not able to get full screen working. Maybe I'm missing a driver?